# How can I "transform" $\int _0^a 5x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}dx$ into $-\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}}{4} + e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to prove that $\int _0^a 5x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}dx=-20ae^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}+20be^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}$, since $\int _0^a e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}dx=be^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}$. I know that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}\right)=-\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}}{4}+e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}$, so I thought about transforming $\int _0^a 5x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}dx$ into $5\left(-4\right)\int _0^a\left[-\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}}{4}+e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}-e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}\:\right]dx$, but the transformation doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Check the error function definition.

Comment: How can there be an $x$ after integration? Everything should depend on $a$. $x$ is the integration variable. Also what is $b$?

Comment: In $\int _0^a e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}dx=be^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}$ what is $b$? And it would be better (imo) if you can write the long expressions in display mode.

Comment: $\int_0^a x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}dx$ cannot be a closed form expression!  It can only be expressed in terms of erf.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever asked you to "prove" this
is playing a joke on you.
$\int x^n e^{x^2}dx$
is integrable in finite terms
only for odd $n$.
For even $n$,
this can not be done.

A search for
"integration in finite terms"
will come up with many useful references.